# Open bootstrap modal after axios http call in react

Tags: reactjs, react-native, bootstrap-4, axios

I made an HTTP call in react using Axios. It works perfectly fine. But when I try to open a bootstrap 4 modal after HTTP call success. It shows me an error 'modal is not a function'. I try a number of ways to solve this but unable to solve the problem. I didn't upload the whole code as it is quite long. Let me know in the comments if you want any additional code sample. Please help.

```
import $ from 'jquery';
import '../assets/css/signup.css';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

import axios from 'axios';
import SuccessMessage from './dashboard/SuccessMessage';



class SignUp extends React.Component{
    constructor()
    {
        super()
        this.state={
            firstName:'',
            lastName:'',
            email:'',
            phoneNumber:'',
            password:'',
            confirmPassword:'',
            isSignUp:false

        }
    } 
    componentDidUpdate()
    {
       if(this.state.isSignUp === true)
       {
        let user = {
            firstName: this.state.firstName,
            lastName: this.state.lastName,
            email:this.state.email,
            phoneNumber:this.state.phoneNumber,
            password:this.state.password
        }
        console.log(user);
        var first_name = user.firstName;
        var last_name=user.lastName;
        var email=user.email;
        var phone_no=user.phoneNumber;
        var password = user.password;

        axios.post("http://ec2-14-2a9-69-0b6.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:4000/dashboard/register", {
            first_name,
            last_name,
                email,
                phone_no,
                password
            }, {
                headers: header
            })
            .then(res => {
                console.log(res);
                if(res.status === 200 && res.data.success === true)
                {
                    setTimeout(() =>
                    {
                        $('#signup-success').modal('show');
                    },200)


                }
            })
       }
    }

handleSubmit=(e) =>
    {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.setState({isSignUp:true});
    }

render()
{
return(
     <SuccessMessage heading="Sign Up Successfully!" description="Please login in to access your account"  iconClass="fa fa-check bg-golden flex all-center border-radius-50"  modalId="signup-success"/>
)
}
```

Success Message component

```
<div className="modal" id={this.props.modalId}>
  <div className="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered">

    <div className="modal-content">
    <div className="modal-header">
        <h4 className="modal-title">Modal Heading</h4>
        <button type="button" className="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
      </div>
      <div className="modal-body align-center" style={style}>
          <i style={icon} className={this.props.iconClass} ></i>
        <h3 className="heading color-black">{this.props.heading}</h3>
        <p className="paragraph color-black">{this.props.description}</p>
      </div>
      <div className="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" className="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hmmm, mixing jquery with react generally doesn't work well, you have to be extrememly careful. Jquery typically operates directly on the DOM, which is a react anti-pattern. React doesn't track the DOM to determine when it needs to rerender. Can you share how your modal is rendered in react? (Is it even in react?). Also, Boostrap comes in a react flavor as well (react-boostrap). If you're not already using it, it may help.

Comment: @DrewReese I added my bootstrap modal code.

Comment: Why don't you use https://react-bootstrap.netlify.app/components/modal/#modals-live for working with react+bootstrap. You don't need JQuery in your react code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try not to use jquery and react together. You could achieve what you are saying using the react state:

```
class SignUp extends React.Component{
    constructor()
    {
        super()
        this.state={
            firstName:'',
            lastName:'',
            email:'',
            phoneNumber:'',
            password:'',
            confirmPassword:'',
            isSignUp:false,
            showModal: false

        }
    } 
componentDidUpdate()
{
   if(this.state.isSignUp === true)
   {
    let user = {
        firstName: this.state.firstName,
        lastName: this.state.lastName,
        email:this.state.email,
        phoneNumber:this.state.phoneNumber,
        password:this.state.password
    }
    console.log(user);
    var first_name = user.firstName;
    var last_name=user.lastName;
    var email=user.email;
    var phone_no=user.phoneNumber;
    var password = user.password;

    axios.post("http://ec2-14-2a9-69-0b6.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:4000/dashboard/register", {
        first_name,
        last_name,
            email,
            phone_no,
            password
        }, {
            headers: header
        })
        .then(res => {
            console.log(res);
            if(res.status === 200 && res.data.success === true)
            {
                setTimeout(() =>
                {
                    this.setState({ showModal: true });
                },200)


            }
        })
   }
}

handleSubmit=(e) =>
    {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.setState({isSignUp:true});
    }

render()
{
return(
<div>
{
this.state.showModal &&
     <SuccessMessage heading="Sign Up Successfully!" description="Please login in to access your account"  iconClass="fa fa-check bg-golden flex all-center border-radius-50"  modalId="signup-success"/>
</div>
)
}
```

Also, I guess you got a display: none or something in the modal as you are doing a .show using jquery. Put that to display always as it will be only shown if the state is true.

Answer (score 0):

Actually getting the Bootstrap Modal to display using React (without jQuery) requires DOM manipulation. Bootstrap 4 uses jQuery to add a modal backdrop element, adds the `modal-open` class to the body, and finally adds `display:block` to the `.modal` wrapper.

This is why it's preferable to using reactstrap, react-bootstrap, etc... since they've already componentized the Bootstrap Modal.

If you *must* show (toggle) the Bootstrap Modal in React *without* jQuery (or other component framework), here's an example:

```
class SuccessMessage extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.toggle = this.toggle.bind(this);
    this.state = {
        modalClasses: ['modal','fade']
    }
  }

  toggle() {
    document.body.className += ' modal-open'
    let modalClasses = this.state.modalClasses

    if (modalClasses.indexOf('show') > -1) {
        modalClasses.pop()

        //hide backdrop
        let backdrop = document.querySelector('.modal-backdrop')
        document.body.removeChild(backdrop)
    }
    else {
        modalClasses.push('show')

        //show backdrop
        let backdrop = document.createElement('div')
        backdrop.classList = "modal-backdrop fade show"
        document.body.appendChild(backdrop)
    }

    this.setState({
        modalClasses
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div
        id="messageModal"
        className={this.state.modalClasses.join(' ')}
        tabIndex="-1"
        role="dialog"
        aria-hidden="true"
        ref="messageModal"
      >
        <div className="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered modal-lg">
          <div className="modal-content">
            <div className="modal-header">
              <h4>
                Success
              </h4>
              ...
            </div>
            <div className="modal-body">
              ...
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Working Demo: https://codeply.com/p/4EV36QjwCB